# How to query a table with dates so that the output is in this specific summarized form?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have the following table (called `StayDateInfo`) in my `SQL Server` database. The table contains around 2 million records.

```
ResaID   StayDate    RoomCat
 100     2018-03-01    STD
 100     2018-03-02    STD
 150     2018-04-10    STD
 150     2018-04-11    STD
 150     2018-04-12    STD
 150     2018-04-13    DLX
```

I need my T-Sql query to provide the following output:

```
 ResaID   RoomCat    StartDate    EndDate      Length
 100      STD        2018-03-01   2018-03-02      2
 150      STD        2018-04-10   2018-04-12      3
 150      DLX        2018-04-13   2018-04-13      1
```

The `Length` column is basically the count of number of days between the `StartDate` and the `EndDate`.

How to write the T-SQl query to achieve this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by` clause

```
select ResaID, RoomCat,
       min(StayDate) as StartDate,
       max(StayDate) as EndDate,
       datediff(day, min(StayDate), max(StayDate))+1 as Length
from StayDateInfo s
group by ResaID, RoomCat
```

Comment: The `DATEDIFF` needs a +1, as `DATEDIFF(DAY,'20180413','20180413')` would return 0, not 1 (as the OP requires).

Answer (score 0):

The following query works

```
SELECT ResaID,RoomCat,MIN(StayDate),MAX(StayDate),datediff(D,MIN(StayDate),MAX(StayDate)) +1 
FROM #TEMP_TABLE 
GROUP BY ResaID,RoomCat
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need just aggregate by the two columns unique indentifiques each row to get the **start** and **end** dates.
To get the lenght just get the `DATEDIFF` from both dates.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StayDateInfo]
(
    ResaID int not null
   ,StayDate date not null
   ,RoomCat char(3) not null
)

GO

insert into [dbo].[StayDateInfo]
(ResaID, StayDate, RoomCat)
values
 (100,     '2018-03-01',    'STD')
,(100,     '2018-03-02',    'STD')
,(150,     '2018-04-10',    'STD')
,(150,     '2018-04-11',    'STD')
,(150,     '2018-04-12',    'STD')
,(150,     '2018-04-13',    'DLX')
GO

select * from [dbo].[StayDateInfo]

select sdi.ResaID, sdi.RoomCat
      , min(sdi.StayDate) as [StartDate]
      , max(sdi.StayDate) as [EndDate]
      , DATEDIFF(DAY, min(sdi.StayDate), max(sdi.StayDate)) + 1 as [Length]
from [dbo].[StayDateInfo] sdi
group by sdi.ResaID, sdi.RoomCat
```

The output is exactly what you are asking for.